# How to differentiate Subsystem and MATLAB Function Block with find_system()

Tags: matlab, find, system, simulink

I have a model with many **Subsystem** blocks and many **MATLAB Function** blocks. I'm trying to use `find_system` to store all Subsystem blocks but as the type of both blocks is *Subsystem* i can't store Subsystems with this code:

```
find_system('model', 'SearchDepth', 1, 'BlockType', 'SubSystem');
```

How can i limit to only Subsystems ?

Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subsystems are virtual and not atomic, then you can use something like this:

```
get_param(gcb,'IsSubsystemVirtual')
```

This will return `on` for a normal (standard) subsystem, and `off` for a MATLAB Function block.

Comment: Thank you ! I just found the opposite way `strcmp(gcb, 'SFBlockType'), 'MATLAB Function');`